# Using seperation of variables in Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to use separation of variables method to solve

$$ u_t = 9u_{xx}, \quad 0<x<1,\quad t>0$$

$$ u_x(0,t) = 0$$

$$u(1,t)=u(0,t) $$

$$u(x,0) = \sin\pi x, \quad 0 \leq x \le 1$$

and find an approximation (actual number) for large $t$.

Here are my workings so far but I am running into some problems.

Assume $u(x,t) = F(x)G(t)$ so that

$$u_x = F'G, u_{xx} = F''G, u_t = FG'$$

Thus our equation PDE becomes,

$$9F''G = FG' $$

Rearranging this equation yields,

$$\frac{F''(x)}{F(x)} = \frac{G'(t)}{9G(t)} = \lambda$$

Thus we form two ODE'S,

$$F''-\lambda F = 0$$
$$G'-9\lambda G = 0 $$

Using the B.C $u_x(0,t) = 0$ gives $F'(0) = 0 $ with $A\ne 0$

Thus we solve $F'' - \lambda F = 0$ using the above B

Then if $\lambda = 0 $ then $F(x) = Ax + B$ and $F'(0) = 0 $ gives $A = 0$.

But how do I use the other BC to determine $B?$

Then if $\lambda > 0 $ then the characteristic equation is $r^2 - \lambda = 0$ which has real, unequal roots $r = \pm \sqrt{\lambda }$. Then,

$$F(x) = Ae^{\sqrt \lambda x } + B e^{-\sqrt \lambda x }$$

See that $F'(0) = 0 = \sqrt \lambda [Ae^0-Be^0]$ so $A=B$, but how do I use the other BC to determine $B$

Finally if $\lambda = -p^2<0$ then the characteristic eqn $r^2 - \lambda = r^2 - p^2 = 0 $ which has complex roots $r=\pm pi$. Thus $F(x) = A\cos px + B\sin px$.

Then, $$F'(0) = 0 = -Ap\sin 0 + Bp\cos 0 = Bp$$
Then $B = 0$ But how do I use the other BC to determine $A$

After this I know I must do the same procedure for $G'-9 \lambda G = 0 $

Comment: the last boundary condition gives you a hint that $F(x)=Asin(\pi x)$

Comment: @Vasya so how do I use that? could you submit an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes:** Going through your attempt, there's a few things you were caught up on. The first is, determining what the last constant is. For aboundary value problem, your general only needs to be correct up to a multiplicative constant. If there's only one constant after applying all the B.C, you don't need to solve for it. The second thing is, use all of the B.C. provided. You correctly noted that $F'(0) = 0$, but you didn't use the other B.Cm which is $F(0) = F(1)$

**Solution:**
Applying separation of variables to $u(x,t) = F(x)G(t)$ gives
$$ F'' - \lambda F = 0, \quad G' - 9\lambda G = 0 $$

The boundary conditions give
$$ F'(0) = 0 $$ 
$$ F(0) = F(1) $$

**Case 1:** $\lambda = 0$
$$ F(x) = Ax + B $$
$$ G(t) = C $$

The first B.C. implies $A = 0$, which means $F(x)$ must be a constant, which also satisfies the second B.C. There's no constraint on $G(t)$, so it is also a constant. The solution for this case is a constant $u(x,t) = c$

**Case 2:** $\lambda > 0$
$$ F(x) = Ae^{\sqrt\lambda x} + Be^{-\sqrt\lambda x} $$
$$ G(t) = e^{9\lambda t} $$

$$F'(0) = 0$$ implies $A-B = 0$ or $A=B$. This reduces to
$$F(x) = A(e^{\sqrt \lambda x} + e^{-\sqrt \lambda x})$$

Then
$$ F(0) = 2A = A(e^{\sqrt\lambda} + e^{-\sqrt\lambda}) = F(1)$$

This could either mean $A=0$, which means $F(x) = 0$, a trivial solution, or $e^{\sqrt\lambda} + e^{-\sqrt\lambda} = 2$, which the only solution is $\lambda = 0$, which contradicts our assumption that $\lambda > 0$

Either way, we conclude that the case $\lambda > 0$ yields no solution

**Case 3:** $\lambda < 0$ or $\lambda = -p^2$
$$ F(x) = A\cos(px) + B\sin(px)$$
$$ G(t) = \exp(-9p^2t) $$

The first B.C. gives $B = 0$, which reduces to $F(x) = A\cos(px)$, then the second B.C. gives
$$ F(0) = A = A\cos p = F(1) $$

which means either $A = 0$ (giving a trivial solution again), or $\cos p = 1$, giving $p = 2n\pi$, so our solution is
$$F_n(x) = \cos (2n\pi x) $$
$$G_n(t) = \exp(-36n^2\pi^2 t) $$

Combining what we have, and using the law of superposition, the general solution has the form
$$ u(x,t) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos(2n\pi x) \exp(-36n^2\pi^2 t) $$

We can use our final B.C.
$$ u(x,0) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos(2n\pi x) = \sin (\pi x) $$

Now you must compute the Fourier series expansion of the RHS to determine the remaining constants

$$ A_0 = \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) dx $$
$$ A_n = 2\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x) \cos(2n\pi x) dx $$

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer! two questions, first, in the PDE $u_t=9u_{xx}$ there is the coefficient 9 on the right hand side, in your answer this does not factor in. So does this 9 have no play in the result?

Comment: and secondly $$ A_0 = \int_0^1 \sin (\pi x) dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \approx 0.63662$$ and $$ A_n = 2\int_0^1 \sin(\pi x) \cos(2n\pi x) dx  =\frac{4cos^2(\pi n)}{\pi - 4\pi n^2} $$ so then do I just plug this into $$ u(x,t) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cos(2n\pi x) \exp(-4n^2\pi^2 t) $$ and if so then what is the approximation of the value(actual number) for very large $t$

Comment: I'll update the answer to correct for the constant. You can take the limit of $u(x,t)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$. What will happen to the exponential terms?

Comment: beat me to it, well done

Comment: @Dylan I am not quite sure how to complete the fourier series to determine the constants, then how would I estimate?

Comment: The Fourier series coefficients are given by the integrals that you calculated. If you don't understand how to derive those integrals, I'd suggest you do a review on Fourier series.

Again, the "approximation" for large $t$ is the limit of your solution for $u(x,t)$ with $t \rightarrow \infty$. All terms with the decaying exponential will drop to $0$, except for the constant $A_0$

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest using separation of variables for this. Here is an similar example from a problem I did in PDE, hope this help.

**Question:**

> Solve the inhomogeneous system:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> u_t = u_{xx} \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0 < x < 1, t > 0\\
> u(0,t) = e^{t}\\
> u(1,t) = 0\\
> u(x,0) = \sin(\pi x)
> \end{cases}$$

**Solution:**

Using Fourier sine series,
\begin{align*}
u(x,t) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\hat{u}_n(t)\sin(n\pi x) \ \ \text{where} \ \ \hat{u}_n(t) = 2\int_{0}^{1}u(x,t)\sin(n\pi x)dx\\
u_t(x,t) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\hat{v}_m(t)\sin(n\pi x) \ \ \text{where} \ \ \hat{v}_m(t) = 2\int_{0}^{1}u_t(x,t)\sin(n\pi x)dx = \frac{d}{dt}(\hat{u}_n(t))\\
u_{xx}(x,t) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\hat{w}_n(t)\sin(n\pi x) \ \ \text{where} \ \ \hat{w}_n(t) = 2n\pi e^{t} - \lambda_n \hat{u}_n(t), \ \ \text{where} \ \lambda_n = (n\pi)^2\\
\phi(x) &= \sin(\pi x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\hat{\phi}_n \sin(n\pi x) \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\hat{\phi}_1 &= 1\\
\hat{\phi}_n &= 0 \ \text{if} \ n\neq 1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
We have 
$$0 = u_t - u_{xx} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}_n(t) + \lambda_n \hat{u}_n(t) - 2n\pi e^{t} \right]\sin(n\pi x)$$
The inside bracket equals zero. We solve the ODE:
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}_n(t) + \lambda_n \hat{u}_n(t) = 2n\pi e^{t}\\
\hat{u}_n(0) = \hat{\phi}_n
\end{cases}$$
Using the integrating factor $e^{\lambda_n t}$ we have
\begin{align*}
e^{\lambda_n t}\frac{d}{dt}\hat{u}_n(t) + \lambda_n e^{\lambda_n t}\hat{u}_n(t) = 2n\pi e^{(\lambda_n + 1)t}\\
\frac{d}{dt}(e^{\lambda_n t} \hat{u}_n(t) ) = 2n\pi e^{(\lambda_n + 1)t}\\
\Rightarrow e^{\lambda_n t}\hat{u}_n(t) = 2n\pi \frac{1}{1 + \lambda_n}e^{(\lambda_n + 1)t} + 2n\\
\Rightarrow \hat{u}_n(t) = \frac{2n\pi}{1 + \lambda_n}e^{t} + c_n e^{-\lambda_n t}\\
\end{align*}
By the initial condition $\hat{u}_n(0) = \hat{\phi}_n(0)\Rightarrow c_n = \hat{\phi}_n(0) - \frac{2n\pi}{1+\lambda_n} = \begin{cases}
1 - \frac{2n\pi}{1 + \lambda_n} \ \text{if} \ n = 1\\
-\frac{2n\pi}{1 + \lambda_n} \ \text{if} \ n\neq 1
\end{cases}$
Then
$$\hat{u}_n(t) = \frac{2n\pi}{1 + \lambda_n}e^{t} + (\hat{\phi}_n(0) - \frac{2n\pi}{1 + \lambda_n})e^{-\lambda_n t}$$
Therefore
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\hat{u}_n(t)\sin(n\pi x) = \left[\frac{2\pi}{1 + \pi^2}e^{t} + \frac{(\pi - 1)^2}{1 + \pi^2}e^{-\pi^2 t} \right]\sin(\pi x) + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2n\pi}{1+n^2 \pi^2}(e^{t} - e^{-n^2 \pi ^2 t})\right)\sin(n\pi x)$$

Comment: thanks for your submission but unfortunately I need to use separation of variable

Comment: would you be able to help me with this method?

Comment: Ahh okay sure give me a few hours just got to the gym

Comment: enjoy your training session, thanks

Comment: any luck solving this via separation of variables?

Comment: I am trying but getting stuck a bit, I will post something soon hopefully.

Comment: thanks for your help, hopefully my answer is correct so far and can help you

Comment: I don't think your solution satisfies $u(0,t) = e^t$ since you're using the Fourier sine series.

Comment: @Wolfy no luck in finding a solution?

Comment: I will find one, had to do other stuff. I promise to post a full clean solution by tomorrow. I can figure it out.

Comment: @wolfy thanks so much again!